# PlatformException(FlutterSoundPlugin, NO PERMISSION GRANTED, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO or android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter, android-permissions

I'm getting this error while trying to use **flutter_sound**. All others permissions are granted right, but "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", it says:

```
I/flutter (18339): startRecorder error: Exception:
PlatformException(FlutterSoundPlugin, NO PERMISSION GRANTED,
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO or android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
D/AndroidRuntime(18339): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(18339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18339): Process: com.example.nw, PID: 18339
E/AndroidRuntime(18339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS
VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras)
}} to activity {com.example.nw/com.example.nw.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
```

I've already tried append tools:remove="androidSdkVersion" or tools:node="replace" to uses-permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Comment: You need to add run time permission before starting recording

Comment: You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission to request permissions. There are other plugins for that purpose, but 2-3 months ago this was the only one that worked properly for me.

Comment: I'm already asking for runtime permissions and also using pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission plugin. All others permissions that I ask for runtime permission work properly and are granted, but only this storage one don't, it does not even request permission, just set for "denied never ask".

Answer (score 0):

Permission needs to be granted for `flutter_sound` plugin. The package doesn't provide a permission handler that will handle the required permissions. One plugin that you can use is the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin. You can also check out the [sample](https://github.com/Canardoux/flutter_sound/tree/master/flutter_sound/example) provided in the flutter_sound plugin that you can try.